# Number of parameters in field_container method from Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

This is the method definition of field_container in Spree:

```
# File 'app/helpers/spree/admin/base_helper.rb', line 4

def field_container(model, method, options = {}, &block)
  css_classes = options[:class].to_a
  css_classes << 'field'
  if error_message_on(model, method).present?
    css_classes << 'withError'
  end
  content_tag(:div, capture(&block), :class => css_classes.join(' '), :id => "#{model}_#{method}_field")
end
```

But in use only `method` seems to be needed. E.g.

```
<%= f.field_container :sale_price do %>
  <%= f.label :sale_price, raw(Spree.t(:sale_price) + content_tag(:span, ' *')) %>
  <%= f.text_field :sale_price, :value =>
    number_to_currency(@product.sale_price, :unit => '') %>
  <%= f.error_message_on :sale_price %>
<% end %>
```

The `div` generated by the above code will automatically have `id="product_sale_price_field"`. Can anyone help to explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `f.field_container` refers to the form helper method in the class `ActionView::Helpers::FormBuilder` declared in
`{path_to_spree_backend_gem}/config/initializers/form_builder.rb`
this method content is

```
def field_container(method, options = {}, &block)
  @template.field_container(@object_name,method,options,&block)
end
```

note that the `f` is the parenthesis object from opening

```
<%= form_for @someobj do |f|%>
   ...
<% end %>
```

so it calls different method in different scope from your mention method, 
the `f` caller hold the object detail so in your case, using

```
<%= f.field_container :sale_price do %>
  ..
<% end %>
```

is as same as doing

```
<%= field_container @product, :sale_price do %>
  ..
<% end %>
```